# How to send custom metric for a custom dimension in google analytics for an android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to send ratings for a product as a custom metric for a custom dimension which is the username, in an eventbuilder.

Please find the code below,

```
Tracker tracker = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsSampleApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                        tracker.set("&uid", logged_in_username);
                        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                                .setCategory("Rating")
                                .setAction("Click")
                                .setLabel("Rating for product1")
                                .setCustomDimension(1, logged_in_username
                                .setCustomMetric(1, 3.0)
                                .build())
```

I have created custom reports specifying all custom dimensions and custom metrics needed.

In the events report, I am getting values for username and the event i sent from my app, which is "Rating for product1"

But I am not getting any values for custom metric for that dimension and event.

Basically, custom metric alone is not getting tracked. I have checked even after a day.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit 1:

Adding more code lines for better understanding,

The below code for rating bar is implemented within onViewCreated method of one of my activity classes.

```
final RatingBar ratingBar= (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rating1);
ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        float touchPositionX = event.getX();
                        float width = ratingBar.getWidth();
                        float starsf = (touchPositionX / width) * 5.0f;
                        int stars = (int)starsf + 1;
                        ratingBar.setRating(stars);
                        Tracker tracker = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsSampleApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                        tracker.set("&uid", logged_in_user);
                        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                                .setCategory("Rating")
                                .setAction("Click")
                                .setLabel("Rating for Product1")
                                .setCustomDimension(1, logged_in_user)
                                .setCustomMetric(1, stars)
                                .build());
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Rated Product1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        v.setPressed(false);
                    }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        v.setPressed(true);
                    }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                        v.setPressed(false);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
    }
    );
```

Comment: is there any api in ur code that stops GA to logs?

Comment: No. I am not using any other API. And also note that, the event is getting tracked for the same username/dimension from the same tracker.

Comment: can u post complete code